# React Js new line in array string pass through props

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to pass an array

```
array1 = [{id: 1,
           summary: 'test',
           details: 'Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs chuck 
           burgdoggen landjaeger short ribs jowl, biltong ham hock cow 
           hamburger capicola pork loin. Biltong pig tenderloin sirloin 
           porchetta sausage alcatra \n landjaeger spare ribs andouille 
           drumstick chuck. Fatback chicken turkey picanha beef ribs pork 
           loin cupim ball tip kevin prosciutto. \n T-bone strip steak 
           pastrami alcatra fatback shankle short ribs. Venison tri-tip 
           picanha, sausage sirloin tongue porchetta. Alcatra strip steak 
           tail meatball ribeye sausage.'}];
```

Say i had that with the array and i want it to put a new line when it sees \n

```
import React from 'react';
import Accordion from './Accordion';

export default class Accordions extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <ul style={{listStyleType:"none"}}>
                {this.props.TheBasics.map((basics)=> {
                    return <Accordion basics={basics} key={basics.id} />
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

thats what reads the array and

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Accordion extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            active: false
        };
        this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    }

    toggle(){
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
    }



    render(){

        let {basics, awu, IHaSL} = this.props;

        const stateStyle = this.state.active ? styles.active : 
        styles.inactive;

        const hand = {
            cursor:"pointer",
        }

        return (
            <li>
                {basics ?
                    <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                        {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {basics.summary}
                    </p>
                :null}
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                    {basics && basics.details}
                </p>
                {awu ?
                    <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                        {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {awu.summary}
                    </p>
                :null}
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                    {awu && awu.details}
                </p>
                {IHaSL ?
                    <p onClick={this.toggle} style={hand}>
                        {this.state.active ? "▼" : "►"} {IHaSL.summary}
                    </p>
                :null}
                <p style={stateStyle}>
                    {IHaSL && IHaSL.details}
                </p>
            </li>
        )
    }
}
```

Thats Accordion so you know what it is doing its making a spoiler box,

but i need to be able to make it so that it will do a new line at every \n

if you want more explanation just ask as im not the best at explaining things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is, first replace all the `\n` by `<br/>` tag and then render the string by `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

Example:

```
let a = 'dvnkvjdfvdf <br/> kdb kdf';
a = a.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'g'), '<br/>');

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: a}}/>
```

In Your code:

```
<p style={stateStyle}>
    {   
        basics ? 
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: basics.details.replace(new RegExp('\n', 'g'), '<br/>')}} />
        : null
    }
</p>
```

Comment: ill have a look at that option makes sense to me

Comment: Do i have to put it in a div or will it work in a <p> tag too